# aviary sdk - red eye feature not working properly

Tags: ios

aviary sdk -  red eye feature not working properly.

hi i am using aviary sdk in my ios project and is working fine except only red eye feature

it is not giving any error but is also not removing red eye effect as well.

so is there any way out via which i can resolve this issue/ or override red eye effect feature of aviary sdk.

thanks

```
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setLeftNavigationBarButtonTitle:kAFLeftNavigationTitlePresetExit];
    [AFPhotoEditorCustomization setRightNavigationBarButtonTitle:kAFRightNavigationTitlePresetDone];
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setLeftNavigationBarButtonTitle:kAFLeftNavigationTitlePresetCancel];
    [AFPhotoEditorCustomization setRightNavigationBarButtonTitle:kAFRightNavigationTitlePresetSave];
    UIImage * editingResImage = [self editingResImageForAsset:asset];
    UIImage * highResImage = [self highResImageForAsset:asset];
    [[StandaloneStatsEmitter sharedEmitter] sendStat:@"editor_pressed" withAdditionalStatistics:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by customizing the tool order. This is the code snippet that you would need:

`[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setToolOrder:@[kAFRedeye]];`